# Envio de un reporte en PDF con PHP en ciertas fechas automaticamente

Tags: php, pdf, phpmailer

Buenas tardes:

Me surge la necesidad de enviar en un **PDF** un **Query** de **MySQL**. Es decir, necesito enviar un reporte en **PDF** de acuerdo a una consulta y necesito se envíe los días 14 y los días 30 de cada mes. Esto quizá podría enviarlo con `phpmailer`. Pero mi duda es: ¿cómo puedo hacer que se ejecute el código **ReportePDF.php** de manera automática sin que yo deba ejecutarlo?¿Se puede?

Gracias.

Comment: Has visto crontab?

Comment: No. Lo desconozco por completo. ¿Me podría ser útil? Por cierto. El servidor es Ubuntu 14.04 Server  con MySQL y PHP 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colocalo sobre tu contab
sudo vi /etc/crontab, vi o el editor que utilices

añades dos lineas

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
  0 7 14 * * usuario php /mi/comando.php
  0 7 30 * * usuario php /mi/comando.php
```

[image]

Comment: Lo que hace es ejecutar el comando los dias 14 a las 07:00 al igual que los dias 30 a las 07:00

Comment: Funciona sin problemas. Hice la prueba y esta funcional. Saludos.